# неработает sql запрос

Tags: php, sql

Выполняю SQL-запрос. Вроде все правильно, но почему-то не работает:

```php
$db->query("INSERT INTO `mag` (`id`, `msg`, `iduser`, `idmy`) VALUES (NULL, 'hello', '2', '1')");
```

Comment: Уточните что значит "не работает".

Comment: Я могу предположить, что `id` не может быть `NULL` )))

Comment: Предположить тут можно многое, пусть автор раскроет "тайну" все-таки.

Comment: id null потомучто у него авто инкримент, точнее неработает запрос ошибок нет но и результата нет

Comment: А какой результат Вы ожидаете? Вариантов-то всего два - либо запись будет вставлена и вернётся TRUE, либо возникнет ошибка и вернётся FALSE - тогда надо смотреть сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: если авто инкремент , то его вообще не надо в запрос передавать. Null значит null

Comment: @teran *Null значит null* ??? NULL - штатный способ потребовать от автоинкремента генерировать очередное значение.

Comment: @Akina :D так на кой его передавать то вообще )

Comment: @teran Вариант первый - когда не перечисляются поля в таблице назначения (`INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (...)`). Вариант второй - когда передаваемые значения есть параметры, и id может как автоприсваиваться, так и задаваться явно (`INSERT INTO tablename (id, ...) VALUES (?, ...`).

Comment: @Akina я про конкретно данный запрос

Comment: @teran Ааа. Эт да...

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте наличие таблицы `mag` и её структуру. Так же можете в PhpMyAdmin или Mysql Workbench попытаться выполнить этот запрос. Нужно понимать с каким фреймворком или библиотекой вы работаете чтоб дать корректный ответ. Там должна быть возможность посмотреть логи или добавить try-catch.

Comment: На будущее: никогда не надо решать проблемы методом тыка. Не нужно "проверять наличие и структуру". Потому что если есть проблема с наличием и структурой, то БД сама сообщит об этом. И это будет гораздо точнее чем колупаться вручную. Также и добавление try-catch не помогает выбросу исключения, вообще никак. Поэтому единственная рекомендация при проблемах с запросами, это сконфигурировать РНР чтобы он сообщал об ошибках и собственно смотреть эти самые ошибки.

Comment: Вот именно, что корректного ответа на поставленный вопрос может и не быть потому что нет контекста, не понятно при использовании каких библиотек или фреймворков человек пытался добиться результата. Отображение всех ошибок PHP может не помочь если есть проблемы в методе query из примера. Так что на будущее: вместо наездов давайте дельные советы нуждающимся.

Comment: Я уже дал, если что